# Difficulties with echoing counting result

Tags: php

Instead of the desirable result I get:

> "Fatal error: Cannot redeclare count() in C:\wamp\www\counter.php on
>   line 25"

What actually I am doing wrong?

```
 function count( )
 {
   static $count = 0;
   $count++;
   return $count;
 }

 // should print 1
 print count( );

 // should print 2
 print count( );
```

Comment: count() is already built-in function of php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `count` function is already defined in PHP ([see the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php)), which is why PHP complains that you have redeclared it.

If you change the name of your function it should work.